# How to use Offchain Workers to create HTTP POST requests with JSON-RPC body?

Tags: offchain-worker, offchain

Too my knowledge there are no guides on how to write HTTP POST requests to a JSON-RPC API with http utilities that are available to Substrate offchain workers. What I understand currently is that the body has to be a buffered stream of sorts (or so it seems). But say I have a JSON body:

```
let body = r#"{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "someMethod" ... }"#
```

I have attempted to take the Request struct and construct a POST request like so:

```
let body = ...snip...

let my_request = sp_runtime::offchain::http::Request::post("http:://some-url/", body.as_bytes());
```

I have played around with trying to use `serde_json::json` macro to construct a `serde_json::Value` then take `value.to_vec()` (a few other steps to this that I am omitting).

All in all does anyone have a good example of how I can send a simple POST request to a JSON-RPC endpoint, and how to properly add the request body?

Answer (score 0):

To inform the server that you are sending a JSON request, simply include the following header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```